# How to know how many files spark created after saving data frame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame and im saving it to csv file with databricks.spark.csv using the save function on the dataframe. How can i know how many files spark created (Spark is dividing the files automatically)

Comment: you can look at the number of tasks in the writing action in the spark ui. each task translates to file

Comment: It depends on the number of partitions.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for anshul's comment, you can just use `getNumPartitions` to get the number of partitions of this rdd, and that will be the number of file number.

BTW,why do you need to know the saved file number?